# Switch from the main.xml layout to another layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, switch-statement

I have a basic Android question here:

I have a main.xml layout that loads up when the app is launched.  This page has a menu button that I'd like to (when clicked) send the user to another layout (about.xml).

I doubt this is the right.  When clicked this command is kicked in:

```
setContentView(R.layout.about);
```

And it seems to work, I do see the about.xml page, but I cannot navigate back to the main.xml layout when I hit the BACK button on my Android device, the app just closes.

I doubt that this is the right way to navigate between xml layout files.  Can you please help or point me to a page that spells this out for a computer programmer beginner like myself?

Thank you very much,

Pat

EDIT:
Thanks for all the answers you helped point me in the right direction.  In an effort to help future noob programmers like myself to understand Activities, here's a great simple tutorial that I found online that mapped it out for us beginners!

http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/24/android-how-to-switch-between-activities/

Comment: I'd suggest you to read fundamentals at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have a separate activity for your about page? Generally for each screen you create a new activity. When you go to new screen , the new activity will be stacked over the first screen activity. When you click Back on android device, the previous activity will be popped up.

Comment: Awesome thanks!  For me, looking at programming code is very much like trying to interpret hieroglyphs.  I just need a reference point and your answer helped point me in the right direction.  Thank you kindly! :-)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is create a new [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for every different screen. You create each new Activity as a new class and use [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to move between them. This way you will use `setContentView();` only once for each Activity. The [Android website](http://developer.android.com/index.html) is full of great resources.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide links! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your main activity has the contentview set to `main.xml` and you have another `about.xml`which should be set to another activity so that you can move from one activity to another using Intents. I suggest you to kindly go through the developer's website where you can find the usage of activity and intents.

Answer (score -2):

When switching between layout like this you need to manage the back buttons behavior

here is a pseudocode example to use in your activities main class

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && (secondary_layout_is_displayed))
    {
        displayPrimaryLayout();
        // return true to let the system know we consumed the back button press
        return true;
    }

    // return the default value
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: There is no need to change the behavior of the back button. The best solution is to create a new Activity for the new layout.

Comment: -1 as well, the OP does know the basics, he needs first to create activities as advised by Google before attempting to twist the behaviours.

Comment: ouch, I agree the best solution is multiple activities I was just offering a solution based off of the code he had...

Comment: snctin: yeah, in the end, "Activities" was what I was looking for, but I do appreciate the effort! :-)